# Convert TextBox to integer and store in Datatable

Tags: c#

> I want to store Total Text Box value which is the sum of two field in datatable but it give me an error of incorrect format after storing the data

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     nn.Open();
     SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand("INSERT INTO name (id,name,price,cost,total,Date) VALUES('" + idTextBox.Text + "', '" + nameTextBox.Text + "', '" + priceTextBox.Text + "', '" + costTextBox.Text + "','" + totalTextBox.Text + "', '" + dateDateTimePicker.Value.ToString("dd/MMMM/yy") + "' )", nn);
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     nn.Close();
```

// Total Text Box calculation

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)    
totalTextBox.Text = (Convert.ToInt32(priceTextBox.Text) + Convert.ToInt32(costTextBox.Text)).ToString();
```

Comment: To avoid errors you should always use parameters when storing values to database.  When you don't use a parameter the driver has to guess the data type since the SQL is a string and the database uses integers and numbers for some of the fields.

Comment: The approach you take is extremely unsafe. It's liable to SQL injection and someone with little hacker skill can nuke your database from within your app.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you should avoid to directly put the `TextBox.Text` values into the `INSERT` statement. It can be used for SQL-Injection (See `SQLParameter` class)

With

```
int intValue = 0;
bool correct = int.TryParse(TextBox.Text, out intValue);
if (correct)
{
  ...         // this string parses well
} else 
{
  ...         // this is not palatable
}
```

you are able to convert a string into an integer called `intValue`.

If it's not working, check the data type of the columns in your database table.